# Filtering Birthdays at specific date range inside date fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm struggling to filter birthdays at born dates using django rest framework and django-filters (http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

The biggest problem is that using django common filters I would need to do something like

```
class birthdayFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    day = django_filters.RangeFilter(name="born_date__day")
    month = django_filters.RangeFilter(name="born_date__month")

class Meta:
    Model = User
    fields = ['day','month']
```

The problem occurs if the user selects a time period like this:
27/11 to 1/12

In this case I would always receive an empty server response, because by default it would try to get dates with days bigger than 27 and lower than 1, which is always none.

Another problem is if the user selects something like:
27/10 to 1/01 or 27/10 to 1/12

I think the solution is to get my hands dirty and write my own filter, but the documentation of django filters is not clear about how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure how your model structure. but what's wrong with one DateField and then a simple django query.

Answer (score 0):

Just did it, not fully tested but it seems to be OK. I just considered that the time period will be passed as "dd/mm-dd/mm"

```
def BirthdayFilter(queryset,name,value):

if not value:
    return queryset

#considering value will be : xx/xx-xx/xx
dateBegin,dateEnd  = value.split('-') #first split the Date Range
dayBegin,monthBegin = dateBegin.split('/')
dayBegin = int(dayBegin)
monthBegin = int(monthBegin)
dayEnd,monthEnd = dateEnd.split('/')
dayEnd = int(dayEnd)
monthEnd = int(monthEnd)

result = []

if monthEnd-monthBegin == 0: #dates at the same month, ok easy
    if dayBegin > dayEnd:#not allowed
        return result
    result = queryset.filter(data_nascimento__day__range = (dayBegin,dayEnd),data_nascimento__month = monthBegin)
elif abs(monthEnd - monthBegin) > 0: #crossing month
    #first the edges
    edgeStart = queryset.filter(data_nascimento__day__range = (dayBegin,31), data_nascimento__month = monthBegin)
    edgeEnd = queryset.filter(data_nascimento__day__range = (1,dayEnd), data_nascimento__month = monthEnd )
    result = edgeStart | edgeEnd

    if abs(monthEnd - monthBegin) > 1: #if it is bigger than 1, we have to add
        #months in between
        monthsInBetween = []
        if monthBegin > monthEnd: #calendar crossing years
            monthsInBetween = queryset.filter(data_nascimento__month__range = (monthBegin,12)) + Clientes.objects.filter(data_nascimento__month__range = (1,monthEnd))
        else:
            monthsInBetween = queryset.filter(data_nascimento__month__range = (monthBegin,monthEnd))
        result = result | monthsInBetween


class UserFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    birthday = django_filters.CharFilter(method = BirthdayFilter)

    class Meta:
       Model = User
       fields = ['birthday']
```